# jQuery update doesnt work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm designing this code and it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

The jQuery:

```
$('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $.post(
            'process_class.php', 
            { 
                headmark : $($row[HEAD_MARK]).val(), 
                headmark_id : $($row[ID]).val()
            },
            function(response){ 
                this.setAttribute("disabled", true), alert(headmark, headmark_id); 
            }
        ); 
    } 
});
```

and the code,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM FABRICATION WHERE FABRICATION.HEAD_MARK = '{$_POST["hm"]}'";
$query = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$query_exec = oci_execute($query);
while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
        echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr><th>Head Mark/ID</th>
                    <th>Cutting</th>
                    </tr></thead>';

        echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr><td><b>$row[HEAD_MARK]/$row[ID]</b></td>";

            if ($row['CUTTING'] == 'Y') {                                   
                //echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox' checked='checked' disabled='disabled'/></td>";
                echo "<td><img src='../images/fabDone.png' width='30' height='30'></td>";                                             
            } else {
                echo "<td><input type='checkbox' class='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox'/></td>";
            }   

            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "<table cellspacing = '0'";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

And the `process_class.php` just processing `$row[HEAD_MARK]` and `$row[ID]` passed to update the database. I don't know how to pass the `$row[HEAD_MARK]` and `$row[ID]` into the jQuery. Please help me

Comment: just put `<?php echo $row[HEAD_MARK] ?>` into the jquery

Comment: i did this and still doesnt work

`$('.cuttingCheckbox').is(":checked").change(
             function() {
           {
           $.post('process_class.php', 
           { headmark : $($row[HEAD_MARK]).val(), 
             headmark_id : $($row[ID]).val()},
             
             function(response){ 
             this.setAttribute("disabled", true), alert(headmark,headmark_id); }); 
           } 
        });`

Comment: where is your jquery located?  is it in process_class.php? Please describe little bit.

Comment: is the jQuery being echo'd to the page?

Comment: hang on, hang on, post the entire PHP page :)

Comment: here guys http://pastebin.com/At5JC3yF

Comment: If this is js is in js file put *$row[HEAD_MARK]* in hidden variable and pass it, otherwise just simply do like *headmark : <?php echo $row[HEAD_MARK]; ?>*

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha my jQuery is not on the process_class.php. Process_class.php is just for inserting to the database 

`<?php

$cuttingUpdateParse = oci_parse($conn,"UPDATE FABRICATION_QC SET CUTTING = 'Y' 
    WHERE HEAD_MARK = ".$_POST["headmark"]." AND ID = ".$_POST["headmark_id"].";");
$cuttingUpdateRes = oci_execute($cuttingUpdateParse);

if ($cuttingUpdateRes){
    oci_commit($conn);
    echo "<script>alert('CUTTING UPDATED');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('CUTTING NOT UPDATED');</script>";
}

?>`

Comment: Check this link http://pastebin.com/GWhzZiLb

Comment: @Pramod i tried your revision but the checkbox did nothing after i checked it

Comment: @Pramod here, http://pastebin.com/MX69V5UW

http://pastebin.com/Vtz1iREM

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be in this jquery statement

```
{ headmark : $($row[HEAD_MARK]).val(), 
     headmark_id : $($row[ID]).val()
}
```

can you please explain which value you are trying to get from HTML dom tree using jquery.

since you have to either use # if field from which you want get value using jquery has id attribute with same name.

so try like below:

```
{ headmark : $('#<?php echo $row[HEAD_MARK]?>').val(), 
         headmark_id : $('#<?php echo $row[ID]?>').val()
    }
```

if field is identified by id.

Edit:

change your PHP code line to look like this:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' data-headmark=".$row['HEAD_MARK']." data-id=".$row['ID']." class='cuttingCheckbox'  name='cuttingCheckbox'/></td>";
```

And:

change your jQuery code line to look like this:

```
{ headmark : $(this).data('headmark'), 
             headmark_id :  $(this).data('id')
        }
```

Also:

make sure that in process_class.php script update Query should have quote around head_mark if it is varchar type like below:

```
"UPDATE FABRICATION_QC SET CUTTING = 'Y'
    WHERE HEAD_MARK = '".$_POST["headmark"]."' AND ID = ".$_POST["headmark_id"].";"
```

Now apply this three changes and try again.

Comment: SO i want to get the value from oci_fetch_assoc() loop that generated as $row[HEAD_MARK] and $[ID]. Both are the column name. and the screen shot of the result is http://postimg.org/image/tewkyx1fn/

Comment: please post you entire PHP and jquery code only after then i can help you. as well as php script you called in ajax call.

Comment: sorry just tell me first from which html element you want to get value in jquery for headmark and headmark_id variables.

Comment: here is the first page, http://pastebin.com/MX69V5UW

and the process_class.php, http://pastebin.com/Vtz1iREM

Comment: im getting the value from the php tag

Comment: does jquery able to get value from check-box data attributes? put `alert(  $(this).data('headmark') + ' ' +  $(this).data('id') );` at first line in change function and check if change function is called or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50799/discussion-between-chriskonz-and-user1480088)